# How do a put a block (closure) in a variable in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, closures, block

Being used to Swift I have worked a bit with closures both as `parameters` and as `variables`. I'm trying to translate that into Objective-C now. I have managed to create a simple `block` like this:

```
-(void)myFunc:(void(^)(void))callback {
    callback();
}
```

And from `viewDidLoad()`

```
[self myFunc:^{
        NSLog(@"MyCallBack");
    }];
```

Now I would like to put the `block` in a `variable`. In Swift it would be something like this:

Defining `variable`

```
var completionHandler: (() -> ())?
```

using it as completion in a `function` or whatever:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.completionHandler?()
}
```

and the actually `callback`

```
completionHandler = { 
     //DOSTUFF
}
```

How would this translate to Objective-C?

Something like... declaring

```
void (^completion)(void);
```

using (this doesn't seem right. I get a warning that it's unused)

```
completion;
```

and `callback`

```
completion = ^void(void){
    NSLog(@"YAY");
};
```

So what's missing?

Comment: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so the main issue was that that `completion` should be run inside `dispatch_async`, something I did on my `swift` version but missed here for some reason.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            completion();
        });
```